# Не принимаются данные из input

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Сам запрос в БД отправляется, но почему-то, он не берёт значения из формы

```
<form action="check.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
       <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ваша эл. почта">
       <textarea name="message" placeholder="Сообщение"></textarea>
       <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

check.php

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$message = $_POST['message'];

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'lab124');
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `lb_app` (`name`, `email`, `message`) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$message')");

$mysql->close();

header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите var_dump($_POST)

Comment: @AlexeyTen Выводит ```array(0) { }```

Comment: Ну так и при чём тут sql? Выясняйте как вы неправильно отправляете запрос, что в нём нет данных

Comment: Где банальные проверки на `isset( $_POST ) && is_array( $_POST ) && count($_POST) > 0` ? Из-за их отсутствия можно напрямую вызвать `check.php` сколько угодно раз и каждый вызов будет писать в Вашу БД кучу пустых записей - последствия понимаете? А если еще добавить проверки на `isset($_POST['name']) && trim($_POST['name']) != '' && isset($_POST['email']) && trim($_POST['email']) != '' && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && isset($_POST['message']) && trim($_POST['message']) != ''` то даже пустые/невалидные поля из `$_POST` к Вам в БД не попадут.

Comment: @phpBear За советы большое спасибо. Добавлю эти проверки. Просто недавно начал изучать php и много не знаю ещё. Но, на сколько я понимаю, мою проблему эти советы не решают. Я ввожу некоторые значения в поля, отправляю это и в БД значения из полей просто не отправляются, хотя запись создаётся. Не могу понять, в чём может быть проблема

Comment: Еще как решает. `isset( $_POST ) && is_array( $_POST ) && count($_POST) > 0` решит все Ваши проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт не понимает, после чего ему брать данные. Тебе нужно написать проверку на нажатие submit и добавить на кнопку атрибут name="submit".

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$message = $_POST['message'];

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'lab124');
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `lb_app` (`name`, `email`, `message`) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$message')");

$mysql->close();

header('Location: index.php');
}
?>

<button type="submit" name="submit">Отправить</button>
```

И в атрибут формы action нужно писать название файла, где лежит скрипт обработчик, по вопросу не понятно он в check.php или в другом файле. К слову, если скрипт в том же файле, что и форма, то action вообще можно пустым оставлять.